# How to include html template into another html with javascript

Tags: javascript, python, django, templates, include

I have an `html` page called `main.html` that is extended with `base.html`. I like to find a solution how can I include another `html` template (`individual_sum.html`) into it with the javascript too. `individual_sum.html` has lots of javascript codes in the file. I don't use external javascript file because I don't know how if there any way to use Django Template Language in js. I have queries in my view that pushes data dynamically so I need DTL.

I included the `individual_sum.html` into the `main.html` and the content appears but charts and other javascript stuff are blank.

**main.html**

```
{% extends 'stressz/base.html' %}
{% block body%}

content of main.html

{% include 'stressz/individual_sum.html' %}
{% endblock %}
```

Is there any solution to have fully (with javascript) working `individual_sum.html` in `main.html`? Or can I use external javascript file that has Django's `for` and `if/elif` statements working in it? My aim is to have smaller separated files and not one giant.

Comment: You can add your js script in any place of html document. So if individuals_sum needs some js that add within it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use the javascript externally with Django. You can create a separate file say `myscript.js` and then add it as a static file to your django project. Then link it in the base file of your templates like `<script src="{% static 'myscript.js' %}"></script>`. It will work with every html file that extends from the base file.